# API Custom Login method comparison always true

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get users to login to my app. From the client the post works perfectly but on the API post method I have an issue with getting the info from my database. When debugging on my "if (login.Email != request.Email)" the "login" always returns null which is causing the if statement to always be true. This is the part I'm trying to fix. The register method works fine so I have not included. Below is my API Controller:

```
 public static UvwLogin login = new UvwLogin();

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }


    [HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Login(LoginDto request)
    {

        if (login.Email != request.Email) {
            return BadRequest("Email is not correct.");
        }

        if(!VerifyPasswordHash(request.Password, login.PasswordHash, login.PasswordSalt))
        {
            return BadRequest("Password is not correct.");
        }


        string token = CreateToken(login);

        return Ok(token);
    }
```

Below is my LoginDto class:

```
public class LoginDto
{
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

And below is my UvwLogin class:

```
   public partial class UvwLogin
{
    public int Pk { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Below I have added my Client code:

```
<TelerikForm Model="@CurrentUser">
                    <FormValidation>
                        <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
                    </FormValidation>
                    <FormItems>
                        <FormItem Field="@nameof(UvwLogin.Email)">
                            <Template>
                                <label for="mail" class="k-label k-form-label">Email*:</label>
                                <TelerikTextBox Id="mail" @bind-Value="@CurrentUser.Email" InputMode="email" Placeholder="example@domain.com"></TelerikTextBox>
                                <TelerikValidationMessage For="@(() => CurrentUser.Email)"></TelerikValidationMessage>
                            </Template>
                        </FormItem>
                        <FormItem Field="@nameof(UvwLogin.Password)">
                            <Template>
                                <label for="pass" class="k-label k-form-label">Password*:</label>
                                <TelerikTextBox Id="pass" @bind-Value="@CurrentUser.Password" Password="true"></TelerikTextBox>
                                <TelerikValidationMessage For="@(() => CurrentUser.Password)"></TelerikValidationMessage>
                            </Template>
                        </FormItem>
                    </FormItems>
                    <FormButtons>
                        <TelerikButton Id="register-button" OnClick="@Authenticate">Submit</TelerikButton>
                    </FormButtons>
                </TelerikForm>
```

@code {

```
public string _URL = String.Empty;

public string TitleHeader { get; set; }

bool RegisterFormShown { get; set; }

public UvwLogin CurrentUser { get; set; }

UvwLogin LoginInstance = new UvwLogin();

IEnumerable<UvwLogin> Logins { get; set; }

public bool ValidSubmit { get; set; } = false;


private async Task Authenticate()
{
    await http.CreateClient("ClientSettings").PostAsJsonAsync<UvwLogin>($"{_URL}/api/Auth/Login", CurrentUser);
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `public static UvwLogin login = new UvwLogin();` ?

Comment: `if (login.Email != request.Email)` <-- This is bad. SMTP e-mail addresses should not be compared as strings (and especially not using C#'s default of using a case-sensitive comparison).

Comment: @Dai This should just be public UvwLogin, not static

Comment: @Dai what would you suggest I do instead?

Comment: You haven't showed us how you're making requests to your `Login` action. Also, you should add `[FromBody]` to your action parameter, otherwise (IIRC) it defaults to using querystring parameters.

Comment: @Dai I have added my client code